# Is there any free EMI calculator extension in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, module, extensions, plugin

I like to know is there any free EMI calculator extension in Magento 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link.

https://github.com/RishiRanjan21/magento2-emi-calculator

Thanks

Comment: If answer is useful than please accept as solution.